# Symfony change value of days in form

Tags: forms, symfony

I have a problem with the form in symfony. 
I have English names of the days but I would like them to be in Polish. I changed the range of the years, but the names of the days I can't

```
-> add ('DateOfBirth', 'date', array (
            'years' => range (date ('Y') - 100, date ('Y'))
        ))
```

Any clue?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can pass option `format` to change the date format itself. In this way you can make that months would be integer numbers, not full names.

When formatting, the DateType takes locale as the default: `\Locale::getDefault()`. So you just need to change the default locale. It is set in the `parameters.ini`/`parameters.yml` file or set via the routing or in other ways if you support multiple languages.

I suggest to look for more details in the implementation class:
https://github.com/symfony/symfony/blob/master/src/Symfony/Component/Form/Extension/Core/Type/DateType.php

Comment: I changed locale: pl value in parameters.yml  and it works :D , thank you :)